# ContextApi returning default value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I've been studying react and developing an app, but i got a problem using context. In one component I create the context and provide its value, but when I try to use the current value of context in another component, I have `userName:undefined` in `console.log()`. Code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import EnterRoom from '../../Pages/EnterRoom'
import NameChoose from '../../Pages/NameChoose'
import Room from '../../Pages/Room'

export const AllInformation = React.createContext({userName:'default'}) as any

const InformationContextProvider:React.FC = () => {

    const [userInformation,setUserInformation] = useState({userName:'newValue'})

    return (
            <AllInformation.Provider value={{userInformation, setUserInformation}}>
                <Room/>
                <NameChoose/>
                <EnterRoom/>
            </AllInformation.Provider>  
    )
}

export default InformationContextProvider

export function useInformationContext(){
    const {userInformation} = useContext(AllInformation)
    return { userInformation }
}
```

And i try to use here:

```js
import React, { useState, FormEvent, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import './styles.css'
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useInformationContext } from '../../components/Context/index'
import io from 'socket.io-client';

function EnterRoom() {

    const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3333');
    const { userInformation } = useInformationContext()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('userName') || sessionStorage.getItem('roomId')) {
            history.push('/')
        }
        console.log({ userInformation })
    })
    
    return <h1>hello word</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useInformationContext` is destructing the context value, which means it's doing `value.userInformation`, but that key does not exist. Remove the destructuring since the value is not nested:

```js
export function useInformationContext() {
    // no destructuring needed here
    const userInformation = useContext(AllInformation)
    return { userInformation }
}
```

Comment: I did it, but now it's returning the default value and not the value provide by the `useState`.

Comment: The code never updates the value in the context. When do you expect it to update?

Comment: @uKn_70 are you sure? It looks fine to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-newton-ud15u?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

return directly the useContext hook without destructing.

```
export function useInformationContext() {
    return useContext(AllInformation)
}
```

Comment: I did it, but now it's returning the default value and not the value provide by the `useState`.